Tikz: text in the beginning and the end of textbox
Here is some tikz code that makes a nice loop with text (modified from this page: https://texample.net/tikz/examples/circular-arrows-text/)
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper,top=2cm,bottom=2cm,left=3cm,right=3cm,marginparwidth=1.75cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, allcolors=blue]{hyperref}
% Useful packages
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{syscol}{rgb}{0, 0.51, 0.153}
\definecolor{modelcol}{HTML}{339999}
\definecolor{methodcol}{HTML}{3399CC}
\definecolor{implementationcol}{HTML}{99CCCC}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, positioning}


\begin{document}



\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}

\newcommand{\arcarrow}[8]% inner radius, middle radius, outer radius, start angle, end angle, tip protusion angle, options, text
{   \pgfmathsetmacro{\rin}{#1}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\rmid}{#2}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\rout}{#3}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\astart}{#4}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\aend}{#5}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\atip}{#6}
    \fill[#7] (\astart:\rin) arc (\astart:\aend:\rin) -- (\aend+\atip:\rmid) -- (\aend:\rout) arc (\aend:\astart:\rout) -- (\astart+\atip:\rmid) -- cycle;
    \path[decoration={text along path, text={#8}, text align={align=center}, raise=-0.5ex},decorate] (\astart+\atip:\rmid) arc (\astart+\atip:\aend+\atip:\rmid);
}




\begin{tikzpicture}

  \tikzset
  {
    myCircle/.style=
    {
      red,
      path fading=fade out,
    }
  }
  \fill[myCircle, purple] (-2,-1) circle (3);
  \fill[myCircle, purple] (1,-1) circle (2);
  \fill[myCircle, purple] (3.1,-1.7) circle (2);
   % \fill[even odd rule,red!30] circle (3.8) circle (3.2);
   % \foreach \x in {0,60,...,300} 
   % {   \arcarrow{3}{3.5}{4}{\x+20}{\x+70}{5}{red,draw=red!50!black,very thick}{text \x}
    {   \arcarrow{3}{3.5}{4}{60-2}{0+0+5}{-5}{modelcol,draw=black!20!black,thin,font=\bf}{Implementation}
    }
    {   \arcarrow{3}{3.5}{4}{60+60-2}{60+2}{-5}{methodcol,draw=black!50!black,thin}{Method}
    }
    {   \arcarrow{3}{3.5}{4}{120+60-5}{120+2}{-5}{implementationcol,draw=black!50!black,thin}{Model}
    }
    {   \arcarrow{3}{3.5}{4}{180+5}{300+60-5}{-5}{syscol,draw=black!50!black,thin}{System of Interest                  Experiment} 
   }
\end{tikzpicture}



\end{document}


How do I change the textcolor of "System of Interest" and "Experiment" to white and make system of interest go to the leftmost part of the Green box and "Experiment to rightmost"?

welcome! please provide a link if you are using code from somewhere else. (I'm assuming you didn't write the code yourself.) \colorlet{syscol}{white} for example to change the colour of the system bit. if you want to swap text around, just replace the bits of text with whatever you want to go in that location.

Thank you. Your command changes green to white, but I want to change the text. I want to move the text inside the green box.

probably split the decoration and use leftinstead ofcenterfor one andrightinstead ofcenterfor the other. then  you need to change thedecoration` options to set the text white. if you only want to change the colour for some of them, you probably add it as an option in the eighth argument?

take a look wheelchart package
